# ASN.1 CHOICE decode error with libtasn1

Tags: c, asn.1

I have a problem with encoding/decoding a structure types containing a `CHOICE`-within-a-`CHOICE` construction. Simplest example is below.

ASN1 File:

```
TEST {}
DEFINITIONS IMPLICIT TAGS ::=
BEGIN

Test_ch1 ::= CHOICE {
 t1 INTEGER
}

Test_ch2 ::= CHOICE {
 t2 Test_ch1
}

END
```

Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libtasn1.h>

int main()
{
 int result = 0;
 asn1_node definitions = NULL, node = NULL;
 char errorDescription[ASN1_MAX_ERROR_DESCRIPTION_SIZE];
 const char * treefile = ASN1_FILE;

 char data[1024];
 int data_size = sizeof(data);

 asn1_parser2tree (treefile, &definitions, errorDescription);
 asn1_create_element (definitions, "TEST.Test_ch2", &node );
 asn1_write_value (node, "", "t2", 1);
 asn1_write_value (node, "t2", "t1", 1);
 asn1_write_value (node, "t2.t1", "1234", 0);
 asn1_der_coding (node, "", data, &data_size, errorDescription);

 asn1_create_element (definitions, "TEST.Test_ch2", &node );
 result = asn1_der_decoding (&node, data, data_size, errorDescription);
 if(result != ASN1_SUCCESS) { asn1_perror (result); printf("Decoding error = \"%s\"", errorDescription); return -1; }

 return 0;
}
```

Encoding is fine, encoded data is: `02 02 04 d2` for `t1 = 1234`. But decoding fails.

The result of asn1_der_decoding(...) is `ASN1_DER_ERROR`, errorDescription is empty.

Exactly same error does appear when construction like Test_ch2 is inside other structure (SET, SEQUENCE or whatever), for example a `GeneralName` from [RFC 5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) (in case of `Name` choice).

Why does it reject its own encoded data? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good News, Everyone! This problem finally proved to be a bug as they just fixed this in their [git repository](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libtasn1.git/commit/?id=05b093a2ef966fd02a2e93248194778b1caa2d55). And note: in less than a year. :)

Thanks to Nikos Mavrogiannopoulos.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using lionet.info/asn1c

Comment: ASN.1 Compiler is a good thing, but it requires recompilation when ASN.1 file is changed. It changes sources and therefore it becomes hard to maintain big project. So we decided to use libtasn1 instead.